# Process data from GraphQL query (with fragments) response?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm building a site with React and Gatsby, and using GraphQL to get data from our Markdown files. For context, this problem is regarding our Team page that will organize all team members by section, so we want to render a different React component for each section (`Mission Control`, `Launch Team`, `Christchurch` and `Wellington`).

This is our query at the bottom of our `team.jsx`:

```js
export const query = graphql`
  query teams {
    missionControl: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: {
        fileAbsolutePath: {
          regex: "/(/content/members/missionControl)/.*\\.md$/"
        }
      }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...memberFields
        }
      }
    }
    wellington: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: {
        fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/(/content/members/wellington)/.*\\.md$/" }
      }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          ...memberFields
        }
      }
    }
  }

  fragment memberFields on MarkdownRemark {
    id
    frontmatter {
      title
      cover {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 90, traceSVG: { color: "#2B2B2F" }) {
            base64
            tracedSVG
            aspectRatio
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            sizes
            originalImg
            originalName
            presentationWidth
            presentationHeight
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And here is where we're trying to use the data object:

```js
const Team = ({ data }) => {
  const { edges } = data.allMarkdownRemark;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet title={'Team Page'} />
      <Header title="Our Team"></Header>
      {edges.map(({ node }) => (
        <MissionControlList
          key={node.id}
          title={node.frontmatter.title}
          cover={node.frontmatter.cover.childImageSharp.fluid}
        />
      ))}
      
      // repeat {edges.map...} for the 3 other section lists
```

Our problem is: We're currently getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined` and we don't know how to access in our JSX code the different member fields for each section (`data.missionControl`, `data.wellington` etc. didn't work)

Comment: Where does the `Team` component lives? Is it inside `src/pages/`? If it is a non-page component, you'd need to use [`StaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/)

Answer (score 1):

But it says you that don't have `allMarkdownRemark` property on the data object.

This line produces that error:

> const { edges } = data.allMarkdownRemark;

Try just to `console.log` your data. You'll see that you have properties `{ missionControl: {}, wellington: {} }`  because you created GraphQL query with aliases, take a look at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Field-Alias)